# Adding multiple attachments to email using selection from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to attach csv files created in my app to an email by selecting the files listed in UITableView.

I have all the files listed in my UITableView and am able to attach single selected files to an email without any issue however for the life of me i cannot figure out how to attach multiple files i have selected within the UITableView.

I am storing the selected files in an NSMutableArray called selectedData.

How would i go about doing this? I have been searching for an answer for a while now but have found nothing directly related to what i am trying to do.

here is my code so far:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [filePathsArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.csv'"];
    NSArray *csvFiles = [fileList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
    NSLog(@"Contents of directory: %@", csvFiles);
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [csvFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

# pragma mark - Deleting data from Row.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    {
        NSString *fileName = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *path;
        NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSError *error;
        [filePathsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadData];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Delete file error:%@", error);
            }
            NSLog(@"Deleting file named: %@", path);
        }

    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedData addObject:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSLog(@"selectedData %@",self.selectedData);

    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       [self.selectedData removeObject:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSLog(@"deselectedData %@",self.selectedData);
      }

}



#pragma mark - Email Selected Data

-(IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender
{


}

- (void)showEmail:(NSString*)file {

    NSString *emailTitle = @"Your Data";
    NSString *messageBody = @"Attached is your recorded data.";

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];

    // Determine the file name and extension
    NSArray *filepart = [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *filename = [filepart objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *extension = [filepart objectAtIndex:1];

    // Get the resource path and read the file using NSData
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:extension];
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    // Determine the MIME type
    NSString *mimeType;
    if ([extension isEqualToString:@"csv"]) {
        mimeType = @"text/csv";
    }

    // Add attachment
    [mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:mimeType fileName:filename];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller  didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. 
Assuming all files are of the same mime-type csv.
And assuming that all file names in self.selectedData have a structure like "myfile.csv".

```
- (void)showEmail {

    NSString *emailTitle = @"Your Data";
    NSString *messageBody = @"Attached is your recorded data.";

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];

    for (NSString *file in self.selectedData) {

      // Determine the file name and extension
      NSArray *filepart = [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
      NSString *filename = [filepart objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *extension = [filepart objectAtIndex:1];

      // Get the resource path and read the file using NSData
      NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:extension];
      NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

      // Determine the MIME type
      NSString *mimeType;
      if ([extension isEqualToString:@"csv"]) {
          mimeType = @"text/csv";
      }

      // Add attachment
      [mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:mimeType fileName:filename];
    }

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a go and let you know how i get on.

Comment: i just tried the above and unfortunatly it errored out, it did not like String, is that Swift by any chance?

Comment: i altered the code to the following: for (NSString *file in self.selectedData) and ran the app, this time it semi worked, i selected two files from the table view and two files were added to the email as attachments, however the files attached were just blank txt files and not the CSV's i had selected. i have editing the original question to include some more code incase i went wrong there. Could you please take a look and suggest where i went wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I did write that "on the fly" in some editor and did not have a chance of having it compiled or error checked.

Comment: Not a problem and thank you for your assistance, it was really appreciated and a big help.